# Rstudio Server equivalent for Python

Tags: python, ruby, rstudio-server

I am currently running RStudio Server on an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance and am enjoying editing my files directly on the server via the web interface.

I was wondering if there are any other IDE's that have this ability (to run on a server and have their GUI accessible via web browser), specifically for Python / Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python, the [iPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is a very close match to RStudio. It uses a client/server architecture by design.

You can easily use it with the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) distribution.